# Transform and scale animation on a View

Tags: android, scale, translate-animation

I have a linear layout with three images in it. On the click of any ImageView I want to animate the whole linear layout. The animation consists of two animations - scale and transform. I don't know how to perform this animation.

This is what I want -

**Image 1** - Before Animation

[image: Image1]

**Image 2** - After Animation

[image: Image2]

I want to not only animate the View but actually shift the view to its new location with animation. After animation I should be able to click the Images at their new locatoin not the old location.

How can I perform this? Please help me out.

Comment: If I scale and transform Linear Layout (parent view), will its images (child view) also get scaled and transformed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used nineoldandroids library to achieve this animation. I used two animation: translation and scaling.

**Translation:**

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(frameCategoryScroll, "translationY", 0, -yValue).setDuration(600).start();
```

yValue is the the value in y axis upto which I want to translate.

**Scaling:**

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(frameCategoryScroll, "scaleX", 1.0f, 0.6f).setDuration(600).start();
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(frameCategoryScroll, "scaleY", 1.0f, 0.6f).setDuration(600).start();
```

Comment: can u pls share how  to achieve this kind of animation http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2qx2if

Comment: @Erum Its a carousel effect. I implemented such an effect in one of my project. For detailed answer, ask a separate question and I will answer there. That way others will also be able to get help for such an effect.

Comment: i have achieved carousel effect using FancyCoverFlow library but the issue is in animation part how to achive animation once user click on any item of carousel that is imageview have applied zoomout but still not achiveing same result can u create separate chat as i m bound not able to ask question i have blocked for ask question in SO

Comment: @Erum the second part of the animation i.e. zoom out animation is quite simple. Use nineoldandroid library. You can achieve this effect in two lines.
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(frameCategoryScroll, "scaleX", 1.0f, 0.6f).setDuration(600).start();
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(frameCategoryScroll, "scaleY", 1.0f, 0.6f).setDuration(600).start();
You can replace 0.6f with any value less than 1.0f depending onthe amount you want to scale it down. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes i made sample prj its working zoomout animation but dnt know whats the issue in my prj can u come in chat i m usig this animation with fancyCiverFlow lib pls come in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50272/androidians room  @Nitesh Khatri

Comment: @Erum In my answer there is two parts of animation Translationand Scaling. Use the second part just scaling and you are good to go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78606/discussion-between-erum-and-nitesh-khatri).